# Tweepy's StreamListener combined with async

Tags: python, asynchronous, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to implement a `StreamListener` from the Tweepy library to like Tweets with certain keywords, which works, except that my program never proceeds once it hits the `StreamListener`. It just listens and likes Tweets forever. According to Tweepy's documentation, there is a way to make `StreamListener` async:

> Streams not terminate unless the connection is closed, blocking the thread. Tweepy offers a convenient **async** parameter on **filter** so the stream will run on a new thread. For example
>
> ```
> myStream.filter(track=['python'], async=True)
> ```

(From http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html)

When I try to add the `async` parameter, I'm just given a syntax error. I've also implemented the asyncio module, but is there more I have to implement for Python to recognize the keyword `async`?

I'd really appreciate any kind of answer, including just pointing me in the right direction of an async tutorial, as I am a bit of a beginner with async anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without the full traceback, it's impossible to know for certain, but you're likely encountering [an issue with Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1017), due to `async` becoming a reserved keyword in Python 3.7 (see [Python's documentation for What’s New In Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) and the [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ac317700ce7439e38a8b420218d9a5035bba92ed), [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/1669), and [issue for the change](https://bugs.python.org/issue30406)), that was fixed in v3.7.0 of Tweepy. See [the latest version of the documentation you linked](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html) and the [commit](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/18dad6f818c377fdfc0d4f8cf0fb131dec958bb5) and [pull request for the fix](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1042).

Answer (score 0):

`sync=True` doesnt work anymore , you can use `is_async=True`

Streams do not terminate unless the connection is closed, blocking the thread. Tweepy offers a convenient `is_async` parameter on filter so the stream will run on a new thread.

More info here : https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html